# Send a messages from App to watchOS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

Is it possible to send a messages from my App to my watchOS extension, so I ex. can update my watch UI?

I'm using `WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication` to send information from the watch extension to the App. But how do I do the opposite way - From the App to the Watch extension?

Comment: I think you need to use WKSession from WatchKit (in Watch OS 2)

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing for watchOS2 to can use WatchConnectivity. This give you several options to transfer data back and forth between your watch and iPhone.

If you want to send a message from the watch to the iPhone (when both are active) use interactive messaging. Read more about WatchConnectivity to understand the different ways to send data. I´ll give you a short code example.

You need to extend the WCSessionDelegate on both watch and iOS.

```
if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
     let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
     session.delegate = self 
     session.activateSession()      
}

if (WCSession.defaultSession().reachable) {
    //This means the companion app is reachable
}
```

On your watch, this will send data.

```
let data = //This is the data you will send
WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(data,
       replyHandler: { ([String : AnyObject]) → Void in

       })
        errorHandler: { (NSError) → Void in

});
```

And on your iPhone to receive the data implement the delegate-method:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession,
    didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject])
```

Comment: With watchOS1 is the watch that must starts the communication first. The companion App can only reply to a message from the watch and can't start by itself to send data.

Answer (score 3):

### Watch OS 4+

Updating @Philip Answer you need to do after setuping session

You need to use replyHandler Method to get data from iPhone to WatchOS App Extention like this

```
WCSession.default.sendMessageData(Data(), replyHandler: { (data) in
            let deviceId = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("DEVICE ID : \(deviceId)")
            DataModel.shared.deviceId = deviceId
        }, errorHandler: nil)
```

This will be called from Watch App Extension as per your requirement.

In Main App Delegate you need to implement WatchKit Session Delegate

```
   // WATCH OS MESSAGE RECIEVE WITH REPLY HANDLER
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data, replyHandler: @escaping (Data) -> Void) {
        print("SESSION MESSSAGE DATA: \(messageData)")
        if let deviceId = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString,
            let data = deviceId.data(using: .utf8) {
            print("REPLY HANDLER MESSSAGE DATA: \(data)")
            replyHandler(data)
        }
    }
```

In the `replyHandler` you can pass information in `Data` Format.